# Why is htmlunit getPage is making this issues with nosuchmenthod

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, webclient, htmlunit

I'm facing this error while connecting to a website. 
[Website](http://www.txsmartbuy.com/sp)

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebResponse.getContentAsString(WebResponse.java:242)
```

I'm using htmlunit 2.29 and while testing this

```
    WebClient client;
    HtmlPage homePage;
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52);
        client.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20000);
        client.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(20000);
        client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        client.getCache().setMaxSize(0);

        homePage = client.getPage(url);
```

I've tested it in separate new class. It works as normal. 
But while using this (`client.getPage(url);`) functional block in other project,
It gives
`noSUchMethodError from IOUtils.toString class.`

What could be the missing thing here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is because a broken dependency. Make sure you have the correct version of apache.commons.io in your classpath and check for duplicates also.

And BTW:

```
client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20000);
client.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(20000);
```

are NO options, doing these calls during your client setup is useless. Please read the whole posts on stackoverflow before using c&p.

Comment: Yes, I figured out the issue. Actually, I was using two different versions of apache.commons.io earlier.
Thank you for the update.